# Are some logical paths inherently untestable?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I have been using TDD to drive the project that I am currently working on and the results have been fairly satisfying. I did run into a problem (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010773/how-to-set-the-errorcode-of-a-managementexception); still without a solution or any suggestions!) where there are some aspects of a particular method which may not be able to be tested (as in [my example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010773/how-to-set-the-errorcode-of-a-managementexception); briefly, I want to be able to handle a ManagementException which has a specific ErrorCode - but it doesn't seem possible for me to set up a test which throws a ManagementException like that).

So, how does one deal with that? Do we simply accept the fact that some logical paths are untestable (because of the framework that we are working in or limitations in the testing framework(s) that are currently available)?

Comment: I've put a suggestion in your linked q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some designs do not lend themselves to testability.. especially ones that do not have testability as one of the design goals. Generally TDDed designs do not fall into this category.

To answer your original question, I've posted a response which involves using reflection to slot in the requested error code. However this may not work in all situations and is not a general solution.

The tradeoff here is the effort in writing the test vs the benefit of having that particular piece of code under automated tests. If you feel that the cost to benefit ratio is huge and probability of failure is miniscule, you may write it up as an exceptional manual test, a comment to future developers and verify it manually for now. I'd say be pragmatic, if you've spent 30-40 mins of a couple of developers' brain time trying to get it under test, maybe you need to step back and rethink your strategy. Have a look at Michael Feather's 'Working effectively with legacy code' on some suggestions to overcome barriers to testability.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you could say that anything is logically untestable, but you will certainly find areas of code where the effort required to test them would be better spent elsewhere.

Comment: Ensuring that rare but dramatic HW and system errors are properly handled (which is what the OP is discussing after all) is unlikely to be an area of low returns -- so, it IS worth substantial efforts if required (and several suggestions on the OP's specific case have been advanced).

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question, and one which I also found myself contemplating recently.

So first, I wouldn't say some logical paths are "untestable" - at most they are probably very hard to test with *automatic unit testing*. You could probably still test most of these problematic paths with some serious heavy duty system tests.

Consider this - anything you test can be thought to run inside a virtual machine under your control and you can (theoretically) simulate every aspect of its operation in order to test your software. Whether or not this is practical for most applications is another question.

Comment: Simulating certain specific hardware and system errors without mocking (he IS aiming at ManagementException with specific error code, after all) is going to be a SERIOUS practical difficulty in any virtual machine environment I know about. However, a VM (maybe with a hacked WMI...?-) is indeed another possibility, albeit a seriously costly one in terms of time and effort (but perhaps worth it if no easier/cheaper way can be found).

Comment: Indeed. Can you test that your software will degrade gracefully in the face of a bug in the operating system? Yes you can, if you are prepared to write a modified operating system that has that bug. But few would bother to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried answering your original question (and collided in midflight with somebody else saying the same thing more concisely, or most of it at least;-).  Anyway, there surely exist frameworks that are way too rigid (thanks to `private` and friends), and if you can't use introspection to go around that (despite having done all proper incantations), then you're just using a language that's too rigid as well as a framework that is.

I'd be astonished if that was the case in an overall system that supports dynamic languages (as .NET now does) such as IronRuby and IronPython -- maybe if C# won't let you go around accessibility limitations via introspection, the dynamic languages could serve.

That said, it *is* surely possible for the overall environment to be designed so badly and so rigidly to make it impossible to unit-test certain things -- even though I'm not entirely convinced that this is the case in your current situation.

Answer (score 0):

Some things cannot be tested in an automated unit test because the language/framework/situation is just not open to it. The way to handle that is to reduce that area as much as possible and keep it so simple that it is highly unlikely to be a source of bugs or behavior changes later on.

There is also more to testing than just unit testing, and those areas (such as Acceptance testing, QA, etc.) are not covered by unit testing as well.